# Javascript file not found using relative path during Flask render_template

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask, path

I'm using Python and Flask to build a simple interaction web app.
Testing on localhost:5000 using Chrome.

I have one template and one associated javascript file located at:
./templates/main.html
./templates/main_scripts.js

The main.html template includes the scripts file like this:

```
<script src="main_scripts.js"></script>
```

When I render the template using this Python code...

```
return render_template('main.html', session_id=session_id, title=sess.title)
```

The main.html page is rendered, but I get this error in the Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Using the Chrome console to inspect the location of the unfound 'main_scripts.js' when the error occurs, the browser thinks it is trying to load it from inside my virtual environment at:

```
./env/Scripts/main_scripts.js
```

...and not from the same directory as the template.

I can't seem to force the rendered template to understand where it's script file is located. So far I have tried src paths like "./main_scripts.js" and even "/appdir/main_scripts.js" with the exact same results.

Comment: use `<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='main_scripts.js')}}"></script>`, when you are in a sub route(ie:  `/user/info') the relative path will be different.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You first need to create a `static` folder at the same level as the `templates` folder. Then create a `js` subfolder and put the js file in that folder. Now you can call it in your html.
Here's the "pythonic" way do that:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main_scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

As explained [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/#larger-applications) in the official Flask documentation, your project structure should look like this:

```
/yourapplication
    yourapplication.py
    /static
        /css
            style.css
        /js
            main_scripts.js
    /templates
        main.html
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you Espoir for taking the time both to answer and to link to the larger reference source. I searched quite a while for this answer but I guess I was using the wrong terms.

Comment: When I try this, my IDE suggests that the syntax is wrong. Do I need to escape the quotation marks somehow?

Comment: @Rylan Schaeffer: Here is the correct syntax with all single quotes within the double: ```<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main_scripts.js') }}"></script>```